# Jólnir - How to prevent laptop do suspend when locking it

Tags: suspend, lock

I know that's it's not a new behavior but it's really annoying when I leave my desk 2 minutes to wait for the compute to wake up when I get back...

So, when I lock the compute, it goes directly in suspend mode whatever the setting I can set in Energy panel of the System settings...

Can I configure Elementary to prevent this behavior?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0):

How do you lock your laptop? The shortcut for lock is super+L. If you do this, your laptop shouldn't go to sleep.

Or do you press the power button/close the lid instead? In that case, you can configure the action to lock in the power/energy menu.

Note that your changes will take effect only after you restart your laptop. So make sure to do that.

Comment: I do use Super + L or from the top menu > Lock.
Maybe it's related to the laptop I'm using (DELL Precision 5540).
I will have a look to the BIOS settings.